# Как найти расстояние между двумя точками на картах?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Известны только их широта и долгота. Расстояние найти нужно в метрах.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*(Отличный пример буллшита в других ответах)*

- Во-первых, во всех популярных `API` уже присутствует данная функциональность - например, [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en-US#spherical)
- Во вторых, если уж вы решили реализовывать подсчет расстояния самостоятельно, то намного проще применить специализированную [`Haversine formula`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) или более точную [`Vincenty formula.`](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html)

> Пример использования `Haversine formula` на `javascript` можно найти [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Расчет по специализированным формулам имеет смысл производить только на больших дистанциях. Кроме того, если уж такой расчет нужен - надо определиться, какой тип линии - линия равных пеленгов или большой круг, и какой датум и геоид будут использоваться (обычно используют WGS84).

Для простейших расчетов в пределах нескольких километров сферическая формула вполне приемлема.

Comment: Vincenty использую. Но она же в радианах или градусах считает. Или я ошибаюсь? Мне метры нужны.

Comment: @Евгения По ссылке пример с результатом в метрах.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать попробовала использовать пример от Plamen Todorov
у меня undefintd GLatLng вылезло

Comment: @Евгения

- **Вы просто пробуете все *"на шару"* чтоли?**

- [Касательно `GLatLng` в ответе `PlamenTodorov`:][1]

> In previous versions of the API there were lots of global variables, distinguishing them selfs by having a capital G in the beginning, like `GMap` and `GLatLng`. In the new API the namespace `google.maps` is used. So what was formerly called `GLatLng` is now called **`google.maps.LatLng`**

[1]: http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/06/google-maps-api-3-the-basics/

Comment: [Здесь][1] для Яндекса: distance(point1, point2) - Возвращает расстояние между двумя заданными точками (в метрах).

  [1]: http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/ref/reference/geocoordsystem.xml

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать это я уже исправила. Спасибо, еще пошарилась под себя подогнала. давно уже сделала. бегу наконец домой. спасибо еще раз

Comment: Да, *эллипсоид...*. Я то, наивный, подумал, что для **расстояний измеряемых** ***МЕТРАМИ*** достаточно теоремы Пифагора, вот только проблема с неизвестной высотой точек над уровнем моря.

Comment: @avp Да, а потом у нас очередной "Фобос-Грунт" упадет, потому что кто-нибудь решит, что можно Землю считать плоской.

Comment: Так я и не стал отвечать, поскольку она не плоская, да еще и рельефом изрыта. (А ответившего так заминусовали). 

Насколько помню, ноги этого вопроса растут из вопроса о рисовании окружности на карте *в телефоне* и поиске объектов внутри нее.

Конечно, по уму надо учитывать масштаб рисуемой карты, но если речь **о метрах на телефоне**, то причем здесь эллипсоидность Земли? Может еще учесть ее "грушевидность" (если не ошибаюсь в области Южной Атлантики)?

-

Я хорошо помню, как мой первый завлаб говорил, что единицей измерения серной кислоты в промышленности, является железнодорожная цистерна.

Comment: Самое любопытное, что заминусовали совершенно ни за что. Вариант с теоремой Пифагора вполне корректен, поскольку все расчёты делаются в сферических координатах. Сферичность Земли потом всё равно учитывается при переводе в метры. Вот если бы было предложено рассчитать длину катетов в метрах, и только потом применить Пифагора, то было бы некорректно.

Comment: Мне тоже так кажется. Я как-то считал (вручную по картам) правда в километрах для дистанций в десятки километров. Потом проверил в maps.google и насколько помню совпало.

Comment: @Shamov не знаю кто заходит и минусует и по каким критериям они это делают, хоть бы писали в комментариях

Comment: О критериях можно догадаться. Люди где-то слышали, что Земля не плоская, а круглая. И также слышали, что теорема Пифагора работает на плоскости. Вот и минусуют. К сожалению, эти "рагуглисты" (в голове у них рагу из гугловой выдачи) не понимают, что при небольших расстояниях угловые координаты на сфере полностью аналогичны обычным на плоскости.

Comment: 2 @Shamov: с точки зрения математики ваш ответ неверен (сами знаете почему). С практической точки зрения он верен, - на маленьких расстояниях разница не существенная, на больших - врядли кто-то будет заморачиватся из за этих отклонений (ясное дело мы не имеем в виду научные рассчеты)

Comment: С точки зрения математики мой ответ двусмысленен. Я же ведь не сказал, что нужно использовать обычную теорему Пифагора, что нужно брать катеты, возводить в квадрат, складывать, извлекать корень. Ответ можно интерпретировать так, как будто я имел в виду сферическую теорему Пифагора и всего лишь указал, как получить углы катетов из географических координат. Хотя в действительности я ничего такого не имел в виду, а просто предположил, что речь идёт о малых расстояниях.

Answer (score 1):

```
static final double EARTH_RADIUS = 6371009; // радиус земли в м
 /**
 * Returns distance on the unit sphere; the arguments are in radians.
 */
private static double distanceRadians(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {
    return arcHav(havDistance(lat1, lat2, lng1 - lng2));
}
/**
* Returns the length of the given path, in meters, on Earth.
 */
public static double computeLength(List<LatLng> path) {
    if (path.size() < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    double length = 0;
    LatLng prev = path.get(0);
    double prevLat = toRadians(prev.latitude);
    double prevLng = toRadians(prev.longitude);
    for (LatLng point : path) {
        double lat = toRadians(point.latitude);
        double lng = toRadians(point.longitude);
        length += distanceRadians(prevLat, prevLng, lat, lng);
        prevLat = lat;
        prevLng = lng;
    }
    return length * EARTH_RADIUS;
}
```

сперто из android maps utils

**Как использовать?**

```
// список точек для сравнения расстояния
ArrayList<LatLng> LatLngList = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); 
LatLngList.add(new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1));
LatLngList.add(new LatLng(latitude2, longitude2));
double pLength = SphericalUtil.computeLength(LatLngList);
```

В переменной `pLength` будет расстояние в метрах

Answer (score -1):

Нужно применить теорему Пифагора. Разница в широте - это один катет треугольника, разница в долготе - другой, а гипотенуза как раз и будет искомым расстоянием между точками.

Comment: Ну, а искомое расстояние не в метрах. Я забыла сказать, что мне надо в метрах.

Comment: я умею находить в градусах и радианах, можно ли как-нибудь это использовать для перехода в метр?

Comment: В метры перевести очень легко. Окружность земного шара равна примерно 40 тыс. км. Одновременно она составляет полный круг - 360 градусов. Нужно поделить одно на другое, и получится количество километров в одном градусе. На это число и нужно умножить гипотенузу.

Comment: спасибо. попробую=) Гдет нашла что окружность земного шара = 6378137. И раз тут в километрах. то походу еще добавить деление на 100 нужно, чтоб метры были?

Comment: И все-таки что-то не то.

Comment: Ага, а земля плоская и на трёх китах лежит.

Comment: Ваше число очень похоже на радиус Земли в метрах. До окружности ему далеко. Его нужно умножить на 2π.

Comment: Попробуйте применить ваш метод для измерения длины маршрута между между москвой и токио. Который должен пройти через европу, штаты (т.е направления движения на запад)

Comment: @jmu, Вы обратили внимание, что ТС постоянно говорит о *метрах*?

Comment: 2 @avp: Расстояние от луны до солнца обязательно измерять в километрах? В СУБД надо хранить расстояние в 2х полях: `{5, м}, {15, км} (величина + ед. измерения)` или же так: `{15}, {15000} (величина, в метрах)`. Я считаю что второй вариант проще, а значит лучше для большинства задач, хотя это зависит от конкретной задачи (ТЗ).

p.s. ваш комментарий это типичный пример того, как вместо того чтоб пнуть заказчика для обновления ТЗ, оно додумывается на усмотрение девелопера.

Comment: @jmu, 15 метров тоже можно сохранить в поле, которое хранит километры (0.015).

Кстати, в исходном вопросе изначально вообще не было про метры.

Comment: @Shamov, добавьте уж к своему ответу, что градус долготы (в метрах или км.) для каждой широты свой. 

градус широты - 111.11 км.

градус  долготы - 111,11 * cos A км. (A - это широта). 


На экваторе они равны. Вблизи полюсов так считать нельзя.  В средней полосе 0.7.

Для бытовых нужд вполне годится.

Comment: Неохота. Всё равно исчерпывающий ответ уже есть.